# Do we have beta stats?

Tags: feature-request, beta

Can we get some stats? A graph (per day, over time) of the number of:

- questions
- answers
- users
- views
- tags (-synonyms, perhaps)
- closed questions
- total upvotes
- total downvotes

Starts are good.  Graphs are good.  Do we have them?  Can we get them?

Answer (score 1):

Not per day, but a few overall stats are available at:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1288/food-and-cooking

(# users, questions, answers, % answered, visits per day)

Comment: hmmm.  I bet someone has stats. Maybe the devs.  It'd be nice to get some graphs.  I think I'll throw it up as a ? on MSO.